# Error When Trying to Exchange Encrypted Emails with Sender Outside Domain

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I have an end user who is trying to exchange encrypted messages with a person outside of our company domain.

When receiving emails from the user they receive a message that says:

```
Signed By: (There were errors displaying the signers of this message, click on the signature icon for more details.)
```

However, when you click on the signature icon it says:

```
The digital signature on this message is Valid and Trusted.
```

Then when you look at the "Message Security Properties" it shows two layers, each with a green checkmark beside them. The layers are presented as below:

- Subject:

  - Digital Signature Layer

It also has:

```
 Description: OK: Signed message
```

The end result with all of this is that when the user on my side tries to send this user an encrypted message it says:

```
Microsoft Outlook had problems encrypting this message because the following recipients had missing or invalid certificates, or conflicting or unsupported encryption capabilities:



Continue will encrypt and send the message but the listed recipients may not be able to read it.
```

However, the only options you are actually given is "Send Unencrypted" and "CanceL" (Continue is grayed out).

If anybody can assist I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer below:

See the "Add a recipient's digital ID to your Contacts" heading [1] here.

The sending issue sounds like your user doesn't have an up-to-date contact for the external user (including public key for the external user), so they can't encrypt a message to them. If they were an internal user, you might pick it up fro the GAL, but external users will need the cert added to the contact.